# How do I find the most recent timestamp in directory names in a bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have some timestamped directories named with a prefix that may vary, and the timestamp in the handy form YYYYMMDD, followed by varying suffixes which also denote chronological order (not in the most sane fashion). Unfortunately, the title part of the name can include the `_` character, which is used as the field delimiter.

For example:

```
/collect/mydir_20161102_0A
/collect/mydir_20161102_0B
/collect/mydir_20161102_0C
/collect/mydir_20161102_1
/collect/mydir_20161102_2
/collect/other_dir_20161103_0A
/collect/other_dir_20161103_0B
/collect/mydir_20161104_0A
/collect/mydir_20161104_0B
/collect/mydir_20161104_0C
/collect/mydir_20161104_1
/collect/mydir_20161104_2
```

The order of names displayed here is actually the chronological order of creation, including the suffixes, so that 0A comes before 0B, and all 0s come before 1. There should not be any incidence of different title prefix with the same timestamp.

The directories may have been changed or modified since creation, so use of 
ctime and mtime is out.

I need to output the string containing the title and timestamp, with or without the preceding path so `mydir_20161104` or `/collect/mydir_20161104`, but this must always come from the most recent directory. The search should not recurse through directory levels.

I would like to avoid parsing `ls` too!

Comment: Doesn't your code return the *lexically* last directory, more or less regardless of datestamp? i.e. `other_dir_xxxx` will always collate after `mydir_xxxx` even if its date substring indicates that it is older?

Comment: Oh yes, I've clearly not tested it adequately! I only actually have the mydir directories in my test directory stuff anyway. I think I'll just delete my code and leave the description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might not be pretty, and I'm not handling filenames with newlines in them:

```
find collect/ -mindepth 1 | 
  awk -F_ '{print $(NF-1),$NF,$0}' | 
  sort -V | 
  sed -r 's/^([^ ]* ){2}//'
```

So:

1. Listing the files with `find`
2. Adding the last 2 `_`-delimited fields in the filename to the start of it using `awk`
3. Sorting it (`-V` - version sort - can handle fields like `0A` and `1`)
4. Removing the added part with `sed`

It could be made safe for filenames containing any valid character, but I'd have to replace `awk` with `sed` for that.

My output:

```
$ find collect/ -mindepth 1 | awk -F_ '{print $(NF-1),$NF,$0}' | sort -V | sed -r 's/^([^ ]* ){2}//'    
collect/mydir_20161102_0A
collect/mydir_20161102_0B
collect/mydir_20161102_0C
collect/mydir_20161102_1
collect/mydir_20161102_2
collect/other_dir_20161103_0A
collect/other_dir_20161103_0B
collect/mydir_20161104_0A
collect/mydir_20161104_0B
collect/mydir_20161104_0C
collect/mydir_20161104_1
collect/mydir_20161104_2
```

Of course, this is just parsing `ls`. ;)

If you need just the title and timestamp without the suffix, reverse the sort (`sort -Vr`) and modify the last `sed` to:

```
sed -r 's:.*/::;s/_[^_]*$//;q'
```

So:

```
$ find collect/ -mindepth 1 | awk -F_ '{print $(NF-1),$NF,$0}' | sort -rV | sed -r 's:.*/::;s/_[^_]*$//;q'
mydir_20161104
```

And a version that can handle filenames with newlines:

```
find collect/ -mindepth 1 -print0 | sed -rz 's/(.*)(_[^_]*)(_[^_]*)$/\2\3 &/' | sort -zrV | sed -zr 's:.*/::;s/_[^_]*$//;q'
```

This uses `\0`-delimited lines throughout (`-print0` in `find`, `-z` in `sed` and `sort`). `awk` is replaced with an equivalent `sed` command.

Comment: Thanks, I was only hoping to get the single most recent, without the suffix so `collect/mydir_20161104` in this case.

Comment: @Arronical see update

Comment: Brilliant, my lines won't contain newlines or even likely spaces, but very thorough and well explained.